# How do I copy DOORS modules between folders/projects using DXL?

Tags: copy-paste, invalid-argument, ibm-doors

I am new to both DOORS and DXL. I've been trying to copy a module in a project template to any given project folder using DXL, but my approaches haven't been working. Here's the part of my script where the copy and paste operations are attempted:

```
// Where string originalModule is the path to the module being copied.
// Where string targetPath is the path to where the copied module should be pasted.
ModName_ originalMMP = module(originalModule)
string originalMMPdesc = description(originalMMP)
clipCopy(originalMMP)
clipPaste(targetPath)
clipClear()
```

Whenever I run my script in the DOORS' DXL editor, I get an error indicating that the functions clipCopy() and clipPaste() have invalid arguments. In the DXL reference manual, it indicates that the type of the arguments should be of Item type, but I'm not totally sure I'm understanding that.

I have tried this other approach as well:

```
// The same conventions as above are used for the originalModule and targetPath 
// string type variables.
// The variable string targetPathTemp contains the path to the replicated
// file New Module Temp
ModName_ originalMMP = module(originalModule)
string originalMMPdesc = description(originalMMP)
bool OK = copy(originalMMP,"New Module Temp", originalMMPdesc)
ModName_ newMMP = module(targetPathTemp)

// Moving and Renaming:
ErrMess = move(newMMP, targetPath)
ErrMess = rename(copiedMMP,newModuleName, originalMMPdesc)
```

I get the same errors as clipCopy() and clipPaste() for the functions: copy() and move().

Does anyone have any idea of what am I doing wrong, and what exactly am I not understanding?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think clipCopy and its brethren only work with Items. Use `Item originalMMP = item(originalModule)` instead of `ModName_...`